# Set Default Value for Image Field contain Multiple Images

Tags: 7, forms

I've added a multiple image field to the user account that uses the [`multiupload_imagefield_widget`](https://www.drupal.org/project/multiupload_imagefield_widget) and it works when I edit the account.

On the other hand, I have a custom module with a form that I would like to edit just this field (I have a submit handler to update the user data). I call `user_load` to display the data and I can see the data is there in the debugger, but no images are displayed on the form.

What do I have to do to make them show up?

Here's my code:

```
$user_data = user_load($user->uid);
$form['my_imageGallery'] = array(
  '#type'             => 'image',
  '#title'            => t('Image Gallery'),
  '#default_value'    => isset($user_data->field_galeria) ? $user_data->field_galeria : null,
  '#upload_location'  => 'public://user_galleries/',
  '#upload_validators' => array('file_validate_extensions' => array('png jpg gif')),
);
```

Comment: Related: https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/90382/drupal-7-form-api-file-field-default-value

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42919168/how-to-add-default-value-for-manged-file-in-custom-configration-entity-type

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use a [`managed_file`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer%21topics%21forms_api_reference.html/7.x#managed_file) form element.

```
$user_data = user_load($user->uid);
$form['my_imageGallery'] = array(
  '#type'             => 'managed_file',
  '#title'            => t('Image Gallery'),
  '#default_value'    => isset($user_data->field_galeria) ? $user_data->field_galeria : null,
  '#upload_location'  => 'public://user_galleries/',
  '#upload_validators' => array('file_validate_extensions' => array('png jpg gif')),
);
```

Comment: Thanks, but that wasn't it.

Comment: I'm seeing the error: array_flip(): Can only flip STRING and INTEGER values! in DrupalDefaultEntityController->load()
 when I load the form to edit.

Comment: @pglatz I was looking into it and you need to edit the value for `#default_value`. You can't just set it to a file entity. Rather, you needs to be formatted as `#default_value => [ 'fids' => [ 12, 23, 34, ... ] ]`. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42919168/how-to-add-default-value-for-manged-file-in-custom-configration-entity-type)

Comment: I tried it and wouldn't get it to work; my form's field looks like this (partial): 
    [#type] => managed_file
    [#title] => Image Gallery
    [#default_value] => Array
        (
            [fids] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 1195
                    [1] => 1196
                    [2] => 1197
                )
        )
...  So I saw this http://www.cleancode.co.nz/blog/1096/multiple-file-upload-managedfile-drupal and tried creating three fields for there with  a default value that is a scalar.

Comment: The problem with your example was when I used an array for the fids I got the array_flip error. Thanks for your suggestion. I'd prefer a single field with the array, but it may not be possible.

Comment: @pglatz Yes, looking into it, it appears that you can only have one default value unfortunately.